# can't input something in nasm using int 80h?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Basically I am learning Assembly language/nasm through this book : http://www.pravaraengg.org.in/Download/MA/assembly_tutorial.pdf

In the book one of the example is to do below tasks:

1. output on the screen `Please enter a number:`
2. ask user to input a number
3. output on the screen saying: `You have entered:1234`

Below is the script:

```
section .data ;Data segment
 userMsg db 'Please enter a number: ' ;Ask the user to enter a number
 lenUserMsg equ $-userMsg ;The length of the message
 dispMsg db 'You have entered: '
 lenDispMsg equ $-dispMsg
section .bss ;Uninitialized data
 num resb 5
section .text ;Code Segment
 global main
 main:
 ;User prompt
 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 1
 mov ecx, userMsg
 mov edx, lenUserMsg
 int 80h
 ;Read and store the user input
 mov eax, 3
 mov ebx, 2
 mov ecx, num
 mov edx, 5 ;5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
 int 80h
 ;Output the message 'The entered number is: '
 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 1
 mov ecx, dispMsg
 mov edx, lenDispMsg
 int 80h
 ;Output the number entered
 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 1
 mov ecx, num
 mov edx, 5
 int 80h
; Exit code
 mov eax, 1
 mov ebx, 0
 int 80h
```

I am compiling the script at: https://rextester.com/l/nasm_online_compiler or https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-assembler-nasm-online

but I never get to input anything, it just straight outputs: `Please enter a number: You have entered:`

Comment: Online compiler don't stop for reading an input. You have to tell them **beforehand** what you want them to take as input. And they ignore inputs from STDERR. Use STDIN instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51308591/3512216. Change `mov ebx, 2` to `mov ebx, 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me when I run it in a terminal on my Linux desktop, after linking it into a 32-bit static executable.

**Oh, you're reading from `stderr` (fd=2), not `stdin` (fd=0)**.  I noticed this when I tried piping input to it with `echo 123 | ./foo` and it didn't exit right away.  (because stderr is still the terminal.)  I checked to see that's what was really happening by running it with `strace ./foo`.

That happens to work when they're both open on the terminal, because by tradition stderr is opened read/write.

---

near dup: [linux x86 assembly language sys_read call should have first argument as 0 (stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937938/linux-x86-assembly-language-sys-read-call-should-have-first-argument-as-0-stdin)

Comment: changing `mov ebx, 2` to `mov ebx, 0` seems to work, you might want to add that to your answer :)